# How to Securely Stream Vimeo video into Android app?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I'm Creating a app and need to Securely stream a Vimeo video into the app but no one can gain access to the link

How will i be able to do this? I have no idea where to start

any help will great

Comment: This is on iOS, but same goes for android too - https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2016/07/11/want-to-play-a-vimeo-video-in-your-xamarin-ios-app/

Answer (score 0):

Vimeo PRO users have direct access to their own source files in every video file response, otherwise if xamarin supports webviews you may be able to embed the Vimeo player into your app directly using [oembed](https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/oembed)